# How do I realize that meteor schema accepts my specific date format

Tags: mongodb, meteor, schema, meteor-autoform

I would like to achieve that the Meteor schema accepts a specific date and stores it to MongoDB. It works with the date format "YYYY-MM-DD" without problems. But I would like to use the European Format "DD.MM.YYYY" instead.

This is what I use at the moment:

```
createdAt:{
    type: Date

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you're approaching the problem correctly, wouldn't it be simpler to store your dates as javascript Date objects in UTC - thus performing a client-side conversion from whatever your date input is returning - and only format back to european display (or whatever format) in the front-end ? https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#dates

Comment: I think you are right on that. The point is that I need a date input field and don't want to use a date picker. The user should only be allowed to use one date format. Maybe it is an understanding issue from my side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using AutoForm you can use the hook "onSubmit" to format and/or check the format of the input date before attempting to insert/update it in your collection. What may make more sense, however, is to store the date using Moment (linked below) and format the date upon retrieval. This will give you much more flexibility (time zones, custom formatting, fuzzy time ago, etc).

Relevant packages: [Moment](https://github.com/acreeger/meteor-moment/), [AutoForm](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform).

```
var when = moment(createdAt).utcOffset(createdZoneOffSet);
return when.format('DD.MM.YYYY');
```